# ActionBarSherlock Tab, ViewPager and MultiFragments like Foursquare

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

[image]

I want to create an ActionBarSherlock with tab navigation and ViewPager like Foursquare. I'm using the code located in this [page](http://graetzer.org/index.php/2012/03/android-actionbarsherlock-mit-tabs-und-viewpager/). What I want is in the first tab (Friends tab in printscreen), I want to create new Fragment from main Fragment. Briefly, in Foursquare, Friends tab has a timeline that shows check-ins of your friends and if you click a check-in row, it goes to detail of this check-in. My desire is the same as Foursquare did. How can I manage this operation (creating new window -Fragment or Activity-) using ActionBarSherlock with tab navigation and ViewPager?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455046/tab-contents-using-actionbarsherlock-tab-style

Comment: Thank you, but I saw this question before. It is almost similar to my tutorial. According to the codes in this question, how can I start a new Fragment from the first Fragment? The answer is not found in these codes.

Comment: Also, I want a ViewPager and these codes do not contain it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, that´s the menu I want to create with two bars but, for the moment, I can´t.
I found this article in Android developers forum http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html they talk about different Action Bars under the title Layout Considerations for Split Action Bars:

1. The top would be the Main action bar. In your example: foursqare, refresh and set place
2. Top bar: for the tabs. Friends, explore, me
3. Bottom bar: at the bottom of the screen

I don´t if someone solved your problem if so please tell me if you used this

Thanks